# Combine remote images to one image using ruby-vips

Tags: ruby, image-processing, rmagick, vips

I had a template image and need to append on that a specific images on X , Y positions. Is there any equivalent to that function in rmagick

`ImageList.new("https://365psd.com/images/istock/previews/8479/84796157-football-field-template-with-goal-on-top-view.jpg")`

and draw on that other images and generate one image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read and write URIs in ruby-vips like this:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "vips"
require "down"

def new_from_uri(uri)
  byte_source = Down.open uri

  source = Vips::SourceCustom.new
  source.on_read do |length|
    puts "reading #{length} bytes from #{uri} ..."
    byte_source.read length
  end
  source.on_seek do |offset, whence|
    puts "seeking to #{offset}, #{whence} in #{uri}"
    byte_source.seek(offset, whence)
  end

  return Vips::Image.new_from_source source, "", access: :sequential
end

a = new_from_uri "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/Big_Ben_Clock_Face.jpg"
b = new_from_uri "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"
out = a.composite b, "over", x: 100, y: 100
out.write_to_file "x.jpg"
```

If you watch the console output you can see it loading the two source images and interleaving the pixels. It makes this output:

[image: example output]

The [docs on Vips::Source](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-vips/Vips/Source) have more details.

Comment: Consider using the block form of `open-uri`, otherwise it won't immediately close the connection. `open(url, &:read)`

Comment: I updated the example code for the new streaming API.

Comment: I think the block form won't work with streaming -- you need the connection to remain open until the final pixel has been read, which might not happen until long after the `new_from_uri` method has returned. `SourceCustom` would probably need an `on_close` handler to fix this.